# How do I pass JavaScript variables to a Raphael function?

Tags: javascript, raphael

This snippet of code should draw two squares on a Raphael paper:

```
var paper = Raphael("canvas", 1100, 750);
var numbers = "0,0,250,180";
var box1 = paper.rect(numbers);
var box2 = paper.rect(250, 0, 250, 180);
```

However, only box2 actually gets drawn.  How do I pass in the set of variables to draw box 1?

http://jsfiddle.net/xqwBB/

Thanks,
Kevin

Comment: Use four different variables.

Answer (score 1):

Generically, you can use [`Function#apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) and split the string into an array.  `apply` will call the function with the first argument as `this` and the second argument being an array of parameters:

```
var box1 = paper.rect.apply(paper, numbers.split(","));
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xqwBB/1/)

Answer (score 0):

1    var numbers = "0,0,250,180";

Here you are creating a string, while `.rect()` takes four numbers as parameters.

If your params comes in the form of a string, split it and call .rect()

```
var numbers = "0,0,250,180";
numbers = numbers.split(","); // now numbers is an array
canvas.rect(numbers[0], numbers[1], numbers[2], numbers[3]);
```

Comment: string.split does not convert a string object into an array object. It returns a resulting array instead